# .htaccess mod_rewrite 500 internal server error due to too many internal redirects from LimitInternalRecursion

Tags: php, htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-code-500, error-reporting

Whenever I place my .htaccess file in my web directory I receive a 500 internal server error and within the error.log file specifying:

```
[Sat Jan 21 13:46:07 2012] [error] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx] Request exceeded the limit
of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. 
Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. 
Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css|\.js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)  index.php
```

I have tried enabling Options +FollowSymLinks but this has been fruitless.

Everything works locally. Any pointers as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use two %{} parameters in a single RewriteCond.. use REQUEST_URI for your rule above

Comment: this is not true, you can use multiple %{} parameters, this will look for the regex in the concatenated string

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky בכיף :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: That will check if the URL doesn't exists.. that's not what he asked for..

Comment: also, if you want to check the -f flag, you need to check it against the full path of the file, just the REQUEST_FILENAME will always return false

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky: That's not correct, please read Apache docs again. It will only check if requested file exists then don't apply the rule.

Comment: @YaronUliel: Go and read some Apache documentation before reaching to conclusion like this. REQUEST_FILENAME is indeed the full path of the requested file not just the base file name. And even though OP showed images in his example eventually that rule will be needed to avoid redirection for all static files like images, css, js etc. That's why it is important to avoid it like this.

Comment: @BartZweers: Can you please let me know if you tried this answer? If yes then kindly inform if it resolved your 500 error or not? btw I have tested this answer on my Apache and it worked fine.

Comment: @anubhava tnx for your reply - I confused between REQUEST_FILENAME, and REQUEST_URI. my mistake

Comment: @anubhava I removed the first line. It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out. I think this is my accepted answer with a negative vote :) ... not sure why the down-voter did so though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the target you are redirecting too:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css|\.js)$
RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)  index.php
```

Comment: This seems quite logical, however it does not solve the problem. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to prevent internal redirects

```
RewriteEngine On
#removed %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} as it is unnecessary
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css|\.js)$ [NC]
#Prevent internal redirects
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.*)  index.php [L]
```

Comment: The error log now says
    [Sat Jan 21 15:40:40 2012] [alert] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx] /home/sites/xxx/subdomains/xxx/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

Comment: @BartZweers I had an extra space in my expression, but fixed it above. Try the edited version. Also, confirm that you do not have any other rules in this, or other .htaccess files.